# How to design this type of wave background (see on image) into only css?

Tags: html, css

[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kOgK.jpg)

I do this code for making Wave Background but not properly curved.
checked **image** & understand better well..............

```css
    footer{
    width:100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    }
    #wave {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      bottom: 0;
      height: 10%;
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 30%;
      background: rgb(206, 225, 235) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    }
    #wave::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
      border-top-left-radius: 1000%;
      border-top-right-radius: 80%;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 10%;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: rgb(206, 225, 235);
      left: 0px;
      bottom: 50%;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!-- html code -->
    <footer>
    <div id="wave"></div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: the duplicate is doing what you want at the bottom but you can easily change it to the top

Comment: I think that wave in your image is a svg made in ilustrator or other design software.

Comment: ya, i know this image is a svg ,but i want that same into css & html